# Is there a way to make folders open in a new window by default in OS X El Capitan?

Tags: macos

Is there a script for making folders open in a new window by default in OS X Yosemite or OS X El Capitan?

Answer (score 1):

> **Set folders to open in tabs or windows**
>
> 1. In the Finder, choose Finder > Preferences, then click General.
> 2. Select or deselect “Open folders in tabs instead of new windows.”
>
> **Open folders in tabs or windows**
>
> Press the Command (⌘) key while you double-click the folder.
>
> The folder opens in a new tab or window, depending on your Finder
>   preferences. Tip:   If the Finder toolbar and sidebar are hidden,
>   double-clicking a folder without pressing the Command key opens the
>   folder in a new window.
>
> To open a new Finder window without opening a specific folder, choose
>   File > New Finder Window or press Command (⌘)–N.

Info from: [OS X Yosemite: Open folders in new Finder tabs or windows](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19060?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US)

Comment: I don't really want to hold down **Command** and double click on a folder in order to open it in a new window... Bring back Panther/Lion Finder any time - At least I had control!

Answer (score -1):

So I guess the answer is "no" then.